# how handle high incoming data and sending throttled data to web sockets in django-channels

Tags: django, websocket, architecture, latency, django-channels

I am facing a problem in my django web server.

We are using python3, django2, django-rest-framework3.8 and channels2.x

Scenario is we are receiving DATA from a UDP connection at very fast rate (~100 messages per second). The data revived is in proto format (you can say we are receiving byte data). some data gets starved in this process as **Rate of production >>> rate of consumption** we are implementing throttling but still at 100 concurrent users data starves again. Can anyone help us in this scenario.

If anyone has any new architecture idea please share.

**This is surely an interesting problem. This is about stock market feed**

PS :- I cannot post any code as it is my companies. but i can help any time you need clarification on any point.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by consumption. If you mean reading the request and parsing it then you can delegate the processing part to worker processes if it takes time. You should also ensure that most of your channel methods are async to avoid tying it down to IO bound operations. Also use the `database_sync_to_async` decorator if you ever need to access the db in your asyn methods. With all these done, your channels setup should just be doing the work of getting the websocket data while processing are done by other workers like celery or other setups.

Answer (score 0):

In many stock market data applications your same exact problem is solved by having Lightstreamer Server take care of throttling on the websocket (full disclosure: I am the CEO at Lightstreamer).

You will develop a Data Adapter using the Lightstreamer API to consume data from your UDP connection and inject them into the Lightstreamer Server. Then, you can specify a maximum update rate for each client and each subscription, as well as a max bandwidth. Lightstreamer will throttle the data on the fly, taking into consideration not only the client capacity, but also the network status.

When throttling, you can choose between conflating updates (typical for stock market data) and queuing them.